# How can I label images for classification based on image name?

Tags: image, matlab, deep-learning, label, classification

I want to carry out transfer learning for classification using squeezeNet for a set of images. All the images are stored in one folder and I want to classify each image based on its name (file name). For example, if the image name is '1.jpg' , its label will be '1'. so if I have 500 images in the folder , I want the network to realize that I have 500 classes.  I used deep network designer in Matlab and I import data as the folder of images, then I got this training data distribution which means that all the images will be classified as one class called 'high' !!!!!. Does anyone know how to label the images based on image name in the folder? Thanks. 
[training data distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RufMS.jpg)

Comment: You can do that a few lines of code. You can remove the extension from the image name and remaning part is assigned as label if the image name is like in your example. If the image name is not like that, then you can assign different labels for each specific image name.

Comment: the image name is like that : the first image name is'1', the second one is '2', and so on. so, I thought that the system will realize that each image has a label based on its name. however, the system considered all the images as one class !!!!!!

Comment: How does your model take the data? If you need to create separate folders, you can create them by reading image name. If your code takes .txt file that contains image name s and labels, then create a .txt and process the image name again in order to determine labels. It depends on your code. Eliminate image extension, and use the image name.